# Is there an alternative to inet_ntop / InetNtop in Windows XP?

Tags: c++, windows, networking

I'm trying to compile beej's guide to network programming examples, but Windows XP doesn't have such a function. I'm using mingw, if it makes any difference.

Comment: inet_ntop is also missing in Winsock implementation on Windows Phone 8.1. How MS could hope for a success of such a crippled platform?

Comment: Yep, and also missing for Windows CE 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're only dealing with IPv4 addresses, you can use [`inet_ntoa`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738564%28VS.85%29.aspx).  It's available on Windows 2000 or later.  Otherwise you'll have to either require Vista and later, or write your own inet_ntop function.

You could also look at boost - the boost::asio has an `inet_ntop` implementation that works in Windows: `boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::inet_ntop`.  You can see the source code [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/boost/asio/detail/socket_ops.hpp).

Comment: inet_ntoa is available on every version of windows with WinSock2 on it, you can't trust MSDN when it comes to minimum version, they seem to have forgotten about Win9x and NT4

Comment: MinGW headers don't contain a declaration of inet_ntop. So even on Windows Vista and later you can't use it :(

Answer (score 10):

From the WinSock layer:

- **[`WSAAddressToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaaddresstostringa)** (ntop)
- **[`WSAStringToAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsastringtoaddressa)** (pton)

Comment: Note that `WSAAddressToString` will append the port number as well if your address structure has one. So to just get the IP, you may have to create a new address with no port.

Answer (score 3):

There is also `inet_ntop` function in [POSIX compliant libc for Windows (PlibC)](http://plibc.sourceforge.net/) library that was created for porting POSIX applications to Windows. There is no notes about it in [online documentation](http://plibc.sourceforge.net/doxygen/index.html), but it exists in file `inet_ntop.c` at least since 2008 (according to file date).

```
const char * inet_ntop(int af, const void *src, char *dst, size_t size)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use something Jeroen Massar provided [here](https://users.ipv6.narkive.com/RXpR5aML/windows-and-inet-ntop-vs-wsaaddresstostring), excerpt from his post follows:

```
const char *inet_ntop(int af, const void *src, char *dst, socklen_t cnt)
{
    if (af == AF_INET)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in in;
        memset(&in, 0, sizeof(in));
        in.sin_family = AF_INET;
        memcpy(&in.sin_addr, src, sizeof(struct in_addr));
        getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&in, sizeof(struct
            sockaddr_in), dst, cnt, NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
        return dst;
    }
    else if (af == AF_INET6)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in6 in;
        memset(&in, 0, sizeof(in));
        in.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        memcpy(&in.sin6_addr, src, sizeof(struct in_addr6));
        getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&in, sizeof(struct
            sockaddr_in6), dst, cnt, NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
        return dst;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: It works, you are really a lifesaver, thanks. after trying ways to fix the compiling error of  inet_ntop in  vs2008, this one is the perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use winsocket with mingw-64 on windows 7

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
```

linkwith

```
gcc showip.c -lws2_32
```

Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (GCC)