# Visual Studio Code says inet_ntop is undefined

Tags: c++, networking, winsock

I was starting a UDP server and wanted to display the client IP. I was going to use inet_ntop but vscode says it was undefined. I included ws2tcpip.h header and linked ws2_32.lib with #pragma comment. I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Visual Studio code is a code editor, what does your compiler say about it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561469/is-there-an-alternative-to-inet-ntop-inetntop-in-windows-xp (read the second comment to the accepted answer).

Comment: ***I included ws2tcpip.h header and linked ws2_32.lib with #pragma comment*** Does that mean you are using msvc for your compiler? I believe mingw will ignore the pragma